# Python'S multiporcessing.Queue's get() method

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I am writing my first Python 2.7 multiprocessing program (woohoo).
I am using [multiprocessing Queues](https://docs.python.org/2/library) to retrieve data from my sub processes. My question is about the Queues `.get()` method. Is there any guarantee that I will get the full object (no matter how large it is) when I call the method? If not how will it be split.
The doc says: “Remove and return an item from the queue. […]”. But I am not sure if this means that I might end up getting chunks of an object or if it is rebuild by the methods internals.

Here is some sample code: (stats might get pretty large)

```
p = Process(target=process_analyze_db, args=(db_names[j], j, queue_stats))
processes.append(p)
p.start()

while 1:
        running = any(p.is_alive() for p in processes)
        while not queue_stats.empty(): #Is this loop necessary?
            data = queue_stats.get_nowait()
            results[data[0]] = data[1]
        if not running:
            break

#In the process
def process_analyze_db (db_name, profile_nr, queue _stats):
    #Do lots of stuff
    queue_stats.put([profile_nr, stats])
```